# How to retrieve AWS Spot termination notice without using instance metadata or spot request state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I have spot instance running and struggling with 2 issues:

1. Testing the termination

It seems if we use Splot Feet, reducing the fleet size would help with triggering the termination notice. Is there any way to test this without Spot Fleet, just by running only one spot instance?

2. It seems the way to read the spot notice is either by querying the meta data (from within the node) (or) use spot request state (or) use describeinstance API cal.

I can't use META DATA (or) spot request state due to my application requirement, now that leaves describeinstance API, using this, what value I need to parse to figure out "instance is marked for interrpution".

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon EC2 Spot two-minute warning is [available via Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/amazon-ec2-spot-two-minute-warning-is-now-available-via-amazon-cloudwatch-events/). You can create a [CloudWatch Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) to automatically trigger a response in near-real time.

*I don’t have an answer for your first question (you might want to split it in two separate questions anyway, as this 1/ makes it easier to answer your question, 2/ narrows the focus, thereby making it more useful for future visitors)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think CloudWatch Event works in my case (complicates the architecture). Is there any CloudWatch Event API to read these specific Spot termination events?

Comment: You can simply set up a CloudWatch Event Rule to listen for the spot termination events. Have a look at the links above.